# Upgrading C# version in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net

I just installed Visual Studio 2022 on a Windows cloud desktop and I took class files from a console application I was writing in VS for Mac and attempted to compile them in a Windows Forms app on VS 2022 on Windows (I excluded the program.cs file, project file and sln file. These are just the class files I wrote). It didn't go so well. The key issues were that nullable types weren't supported and that System.Text.Json was undefined. Turns out I'm running C# v7.3 and I need 8.0. However, I can't seem to find a way to change this. The online searching I've done so far points to changing the Langversion tag in the csproj file, but this tag doesn't exist in my csproj file. I then tried to include the Langversion tag into the csproj file and that did nothing. When I attempted to adjust the C# language version through the csproj properties editor in VS, is shows "Automatically Selected based on framework version". The current framework version I have selected is 4.8 (I think can be used with C# 8), which is as high as it goes. I attempted to download and install the .NET SDK v7.0, but that doesn't seem to include the framework. In other words, this didn't change anything with regards to me being able to change the C# version I want to use.

Any ideas on how else I can upgrade to C# v8.0 for my Windows Forms app?

Thanks!

Please see my explanation above.

Comment: _"The current framework version I have selected is 4.8"_ - that's your problem. You are on ".Net **Framework**" while your code probably aims at .Net (Core and above). Not sure if later C# version are compatible. I'd go one of these routes: downgrade the code to C# 7.3 or upgrade the project to a higher .Net (_not Framework) version.

Comment: Thanks. How can I verify this and then change it?

Comment: Look at the project you have the code from. It will probably tell you what framework and C# versions it is. Now, If you want to upgrade your Forms Project, I _think_ there should be migration guides ...

Comment: You'll have to switch to .NET (Core) 6, or extract that code in a .NET Standard 2.0 library. Nullable Reference Types require support from the runtime too, they aren't simply a language feature. `I then tried to include the Langversion tag into the csproj file and that did nothing` that would never work. .NET Core has a completely different project format

Comment: ^^ There seems to be an assistant, even: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-winforms-framework

Comment: If you want modern features you'll have to switch to .NET 6 anyway. .NET Framework 4.8 is the last version of .NET Framework and is essentially in maintenance mode. A *lot* of the newer language features depend on runtime changes, not just compiler changes.

Comment: Thanks. If this is the case, I’m not sure why the Visual Studio setup installed such old versions of the framework. I’ll check out the install again and see if I chose the wrong options.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant-now-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 5):

If this is a small application I would probably suggest creating a new project, and make sure to select the "Windows Forms App"-template (NOT "Windows Forms App (.Net Framework)"). You might need to add references to some nuget packages, like System.Text.Json. Select .Net 7 if you want the latest features.

Messing around with langversion is mostly useful for larger projects where updating is infeasible for some reason. You could convert the project, but if it is small, my guess would be that it is easier to start over and just copy the .cs files to your new project.

Comment: Ah okay! This was the problem. I selected WinForms (.NET Framework) versus WinForms. I’m not sure if the differences between these types of apps but now I can include the JSON namespace. Thank you!